# For quik image loading on tableview which is the best method that can be used for iphone?

Tags: iphone, imageview

Does the uiwebview is a good option?

Comment: No, UIImageView is the only option to show any image.

Comment: this really depends on the size of the images. If they are small, I've generally found UIImageView is all you need. Keep in mind if you use "imageNamed" IOS will cache images. Great for speed, but it's also possible to run into memory issues depending on size and number of images. If they are VERY large (multiple mb's) you have a completely different problem (probably not the case if you are using a table view w/ multiple images).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, UIWebview is not good option. For quick image downloading you can use the concept of asynchronous in iPhone so try the below link.

http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/